# Setting up web site on IIS from network location

Tags: networking, iis

I have files located on a network drive that I'd like to make into a site on the IIS 7 server.  The IIS server complains that it cannot find the web.config.  That file is in my c:\inetpub\wwwroot.  It is not on the network drive.  The error message is

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid.

Is there information available on setting up sites located on network drives in IIS 7?